# joint probability distribution in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The problem of incompatible observables in quantum mechanics is often explained in terms of their (self-adjoint) operators having different sets of eigenstates. This causes their commutator to be non-zero. It also leads to the uncertainty relation between the two observables in terms of the expectation value of their commutator in the QM state.

However, I also read that the problem of incompatible observables can be formulated and understood in terms of a joint probability distribution.

I would very much like to know if such a joint probability distribution has been successfully constructed for the Hydrogen ground state, e.g. for the radial position $r$ on the one hand and either the radial momentum $p$ or the kinetic energy $T$ on the other hand.

In my opinion it would be fascinating to know this joint probability distribution, since it would shed light on the intrinsic (and unobserved) behaviour of the electron within its orbital state. The way it speeds up near the nucleus due to the Coulomb force and slows down in the farther regions. And the way its linear path spreads out and becomes three dimensional.

Comment: I think you're talking about the [Wigner quasiprobability distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution). Can you be more specific what you want to know?

Comment: I would like to know whether there exists a joint probability distribution $P(r, p)$ for the Hydrogen ground state. So that if you choose a certain value for $r$, you can calculate the corresponding average value for $p$ (and the standard deviation). The resulting $< p(r) >$ provides information about the intrinsic dynamical behaviour of the electron in its orbital state. That is what interest me.

Comment: I realize that there is an alternative approach. Start with the wave-function in $r$-representation. Construct a test function $f(r)$ which represents the kinetic energy as a multiplicative function. Then evaluate the co-variance between $f(r)$ and the kinetic energy operator $T$. Adjust parameters until the co-variance attains its minimal value. Then you have found the function $f(r)$ which emulates the true behaviour best.